# Visual Studio reverts source control to ankh svn when opening project

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tfs, ankhsvn

I had used Ankh SVN to do source control for a project but now I want to use a TFS server but I can't as Ankh is set as default every time I open the project. I also removed all .svn files so it's not linked to subversion anymore.

How do I overcome this behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean [Ankh SVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)?  If so, add its tag.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk yes, I misspelled

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the source control bindings to point to TFS instead of to SVN.

With the solution open, go to "File" -> "Source Control" -> "Advanced" -> "Change Source Control Provider".

Comment: but it revers to Ankh upon reopening the project